# WebStorm force use of 2 spaces for tabs

Tags: webstorm

I have configured WebStorm to use 2 spaces for tabs like this:

```
Settings->Editor->Code Style->JavaScript
Use tab character: no
Tab size: 2
Indent: 2
Continuation indent: 2
```

However WebStorm still uses 4 spaces in certain situations e.g. below comments, or below for loop starting statements:

```
// comment
....forces tab out to here
for () {
....forces tab out to here
```

Is there a way to force 2 space tabs in all cases?

Comment: Check whether your project contains a file named `.editorconfig`. If it does, it overrides your settings.

Comment: @RamyBenAroya Thanks, in my .editorconfig I have indent_size = 2 but I have disabled .editorconfig override already. I think its a setting someone just for formatting around particlar js statements

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Try to apply selector "Use tab character".